# ajax from same site as JS reference file?

Tags: ajax, dojo, cross-domain

I have a JS file running on my site, it works fine.

Now I want to put on another site with the full url of the script back to my site.

```
<script src="http://www-js.mydomains.com/some/path/file.js"></script>
```

now is it really still cross domain to an xml request on my server?

so in the file.js I have something like

```
dojo.xhrGet({url: '/some/path/file.xml', sync: true, handleAs: 'xml', error: function(result,args){alert(result.responseText+'-'+args.responseText)}, load: function(result){ ....
```

this just dies on other sites (great dojo response of undefined)... is there away around it

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use **"script" dojo/request/script** instead of xhr.

```
 require(["dojo/request/script", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(script, dom, domConst, JSON, on){
  on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function(){
    domConst.place("<p>Requesting...</p>", "output");
    script.get("helloworld.jsonp.js", {
      jsonp: "callback"
    }).then(function(data){
      domConst.place("<p>response data: <code>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</code></p>", "output");
    });
  });
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/script.html

Comment: If still not work then let me know what error is throwing by browser.

Comment: The document being loaded with XHR is an XML document, you can't use request script to process that!

Answer (score 0):

> now is it really still cross domain to an xml request on my server?

Yes. The origin is based on the URI of the HTML document hosting the script, not the URI the script was sourced from.

You should send the HTTP headers defined in the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) to allow other sites to use your script (or their own scripts) to access content on your server.

Additionally, URIs accessed by JS are also relative to the document and not the script, so you will need to use an absolute or scheme relative URI instead of the server root relative URI you are presently using.